# Running ASP.NET 5 on Cloud 9

Tags: mono, asp.net-core, cloud9-ide

Do you think it's technically possible to run [ASP.NET 5 (vNext)](https://github.com/aspnet/home) inside [Cloud9 environment](https://c9.io/)?

I have followed the documentation on https://github.com/aspnet/home, everything seem to work fine, but when I run the command:

```
dnx . kestrel
```

`mono` is executed and start to use 100% of the CPU but the HTTP server is not working.

Here my sample application: https://github.com/davideicardi/aspnet5-on-cloud9

Comment: Your app looks fine, though I'm not at all familiar with cloud9. Does Kestrel's 0.0.0.0 work with dnx?

Comment: Servers running on Cloud9 workspaces need to listen to `0.0.0.0:8080` for them to accessible from the outside. Which IP:PORT are you running your server on?

Comment: @Mutahhir Yes, my command is: `"kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Kestrel --server.urls http://0.0.0.0:8080"`

Comment: I suspect it is some problem with `mono` or `kestrel` because the fact that the CPU goes to 100% for the mono process and it seems to be stuck.

Comment: Hmm, even if CPU is 100%, and the process isn't killed, it should work. Is there some kind of error output or a flag you could turn on to get it?

Comment: There seems to be an issue with Kestrel on Linux. See here: http://carolynvanslyck.com/blog/2014/09/dotnet-vnext-impressions/ Scroll down to **Bye Bye IIS** then **Kestrel** to see the info section.

Comment: @DavideIcardi were you able to get ASP.NET 5 running on C9?

Comment: @RomanMik Yes! Using rc1 all seems to work fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ASP.NET 5 rc1 I have succesfully executed ASP.NET on Cloud 9.

Installing instruction for ASP.NET 5

https://github.com/aspnet/Home/blob/dev/GettingStartedDeb.md

After `dnvm` and `dnx` are installed restore packages using

```
dnu restore
```

If you receive HTTP timeout errors first use (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31975260/209727):

```
export MONO_THREADS_PER_CPU=2000    
dnu restore
```

Then run the web server using:

```
dnx web
```

Note that port 8080 is the default used by cloud 9 ide.

Here my final repository on github: https://github.com/davideicardi/aspnet5-on-cloud9

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna give it a try