# DNU Restore gives lots of "HTTP request timed out"

Tags: mono, nuget, asp.net-core, dnu

I'm trying to run the samples from https://github.com/aspnet/home.
But I'm having problems updating the references. The restore is very slow and fails for some packages:

```
  GET http://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables'
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET http://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables'
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Ini
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET http://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Ini'
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Ini
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET http://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Ini'
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Framework.Logging
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET http://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Framework.Logging'
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Framework.Logging
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET http://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Framework.Logging'
Warning: FindPackagesById: Newtonsoft.Json
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET http://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Newtonsoft.Json'
Warning: FindPackagesById: Newtonsoft.Json
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET http://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Newtonsoft.Json'
Error: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor
  HTTP request timed out. Exiting.
```

I tried with different urls using nuget, myget, http, https.
I checked my internet connection. 
There is a [related issue in the dnx repo](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/1590), but it did not help.
Any workaround to try?

I'm using mono 4.0.3.20 on CentOS.

Comment: This is a known issue. You can take a look at this issue and a workaround mentioned in that thread. https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/1590

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the workaround:

```
export MONO_THREADS_PER_CPU=2000
```

from http://www.mono-project.com/archived/articlethreadpool_deadlocks/